# Is it ok to use Meteor publish composite for dozens of subscriptions?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

Currently, our system is not entirely normalized, and we use [meteor-publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) to obtain the normalized data in mongodb. Some models have very few dependencies, but others have arrays of objects (i.e. sub-documents) with few foreign keys that we are subscribing to when fetching each model.

An example would be a `Post` containing a list of `Comment` sub-documents, where each comment has a `userId` field.

My question is, while I know it would be faster to use collection hooks and update the collection with data denormalization, how does Meteor handle multiple subscriptions on the same collection?

Is a hundred subscriptions on the same collection affect the application speed (significantly)? What about a thousand? etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may not fully answer your question, however after spending countless hours tuning the performance of a large meteor app, I thought I would share some of the things that I have learned.

In Meteor, when you define a publication, you are setting up a reactive query that continues to push data to subscribed clients when changes to the underlying mongo data causes the result of the query to change.  In other words, it sets up a query that will continually push data to clients as the data is inserted, updated, or removed.  The mechanism by which it does this is by creating an `observer` on the query.

When an `observer` is initialized (e.g. when publication is subscribed to), it will query mongodb for the initial dataset to send down and then use the oplog to detect changes going forward.  Fortunately, meteor is able to re-use an existing observer for a new subscription if the query is for the same collection, same selectors, and same options.

This means that you could create hundreds of subscriptions against many different publications, but if they are hitting against the same collection and using the same query selectors then you effectively only have 1 `observe` in play.  For more details, I highly recommend reading [this article](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/improve-cpu-and-network-usage) from kadira.io (from which I acquired the information I used in this answer).

In addition to this, Meteor is also able to deal with multiple publications publishing the same document, and when this occurs, the documents will be merged into one.  See [this](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) for more detail.

Lastly, because of Meteor's [MergeBox](https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox/) component, it will minimize the data being sent over the wire across all your subscriptions by keeping track of what data changed vs. what is already on the client.

Therefore, in your specific example, it sounds like you will be running several different subscriptions on effectively the same query (since you are just trying to de-normalize your data) and dataset.  Because of all the optimizations that I described above, I would guess that you won't be plagued by performance issues by taking this approach.

I have done similar things in one of my apps and have never had an issue.